# Joining two tables and loop and repeat through on column of one of them

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, LessonPlans and Images, that I want to use together, but I can't make it work. In LessonPlans I will continue to add more and more rows, but Images will only contain 10 images that will later be repeated. ei. LessonPlan1=image1, LessonPlan2=image2... LessonPLan10=image10, LessonPlan11=image1 etc. To make it even better, I only want to use the images that has the same language as the LessonPlans.

Whatever way I try now, I get Image 1 to repeat the same amount of times that I have rows in that field. What I've tried with is:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT l.Id, l.Subject, l.Language, l.Level, l.Aim, i.`Name-img`, i.`Alt-img` 
    FROM LessonPlans l
    JOIN Images i
    ON l.Language = i.Language
    WHERE l.Language = 'English'
) a GROUP BY a.Subject  ORDER BY a.Id DESC;
```

Is there any way to make this work?

The tables I use are:

**LessonPlans**:

```
Id | Subject | Language | Level | Aim
```

**Images**:

```
Id | Name-img | Language | Alt-img
```

Comment: Just a html example of what it will look like: http://webbkurs.ei.hv.se/~hani0008/mlslp/main-mz.html

Comment: you do not have `Language` field in Images table. So how can you do the join?

Comment: how do you apply join without existing field in images (language) ?

Comment: Plus how do you link lessonplan1 with image1 using you current structure? Your query only joins on the language field. Finally, you should read a little bit about the group by clause as well because whet you have there is agains the sql standard and will only run using certain configuration settings in mysql. This group by causes the query to show image1 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add column `ImageId` to `LessonPlans` table. When inserting new data into `LessonPlans` you need to insert also `ImageId` based on some logic you prefer.
Then you can use this query:

```
select * from LessonPlans l, Images i where l.ImageId=i.Id
```

It is always preferred to put all the logic and complexity to the part where you insert new data and arrange everything so the select query is the simplest possible. This is because in your case inserts are rare and selects are done on each opening of the page in browser, so the goal is to optimize more frequent operation for speed on the expense of less frequent one.

If you are solving a problem where there is a high rate of inserts and low rate of selects then the logic goes the other way around.

Comment: Wouldn't l.Language=i.Language work as the same as l.ImageID=i.Id? There I already have something that combines the two tables.

Comment: No. As I understood you want mapping "one image to many lesson plans", one image can be used by more than one lesson plan but one lesson plan is using only one image.
By using Language you will get mapping "multiple images to multiple lesson plans". You will have Cartesian product on all rows from both tables which have the same language, so you will get multiple rows from SQL query with the same lesson plan row.

Comment: Ok. So if I have 10 images of each language (Id 1-10 English, 11-20 French etc) I can somehow just add ImageId 1-10 (maybe even randomly) when I create an English LessonPlan and it will add an image that is correct, as well as repeat the images even if I make 10000 new LessonPlans?

Comment: Correct!
In this case every lesson plan will always show the same assigned image.
I don't know if that suits you or you want to add some more randomness, to have picture for lesson plan changed based on some criteria: per user session, each day or hour, on every refresh, etc. ?

Comment: Hm... ImageId is not necessarily a number between 1-10 for English, 11-20 for French etc. because your Id column is auto_increment.
When you insert first image, it will have Id 1, second one will have Id 2 and so on. But, if you delete image for English with Id 2 and insert a new one, it will have Id max(Id)+1.
If you want everything to be consistent in this way, you need to insert first 10 rows for English, then 10 rows for French and so on. And after that you should not delete any of the rows for Images.

Comment: Another solution is not to have auto_increment on Id column in Images table. Then you can simply add Id value when inserting images:

`INSERT INTO images (Id, name, alt, language) VALUES 
        (1, 'pic1', 'this is pic1',1)`

Comment: Ok. It all sound very good. My initial idea was to have a table with images for each language that are randomly connected to a lesson plan when that lesson plan is created and that the lesson plan later stick with the same image (I think it's easier for the user if the photos are not shuffled on every load if they want to use the same lesson plan). And with this technique I will get exactly that. Perfect so far.

Comment: BUT, I also want that only one language is showed at a time (so no mixing of French and English, but shown on seperate pages). Also, not having the images in order in the table (English 1-10, French 11-20 etc) Would make it difficult to assign the correct photo to the correct language when creating the lesson plan from a form. Does this make any sense?

Comment: And when testing it now I found a huge collateral damage. Since imageId is set to equal Id, it opens the lessonplan with the Id of the image istead of the actual lesson plan (I'm using dynamic links to open the lesson plans).

Comment: I manged to fix the "collateral damage". Maybe not the best way, but just removing the Id from Images worked.